# Kotlin @Serializable skip properties with default values

Tags: kotlin, serialization, kotlinx.serialization

Why JSON doesn't content property with default value?

I suppose that is serialized only what is actually needed to rebuild object, but is totally useless when i just want create API JsonResponses...

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import kotlinx.serialization.json.encodeToJsonElement

@Serializable
data class Test(
    val required: String,
    val defaulted: String = "default",
)


val test = Test(
   required = "set"
)

println(Json.encodeToJsonElement(test))

// Result= {"required":"set"}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason [given in the documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/basic-serialization.md#defaults-are-not-encoded-by-default) is to avoid visual clutter.

As explained in the [documentation here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/basic-serialization.md#defaults-are-not-encoded-by-default), you can mark properties that have defaults with `@EncodeDefault` if you want them to be included in the JSON:

```
@Serializable
data class Test(
    val required: String,
    @EncodeDefault val defaulted: String = "default",
)
```

Or, if you want to do this everywhere without the annotation, create a customized Json encoder like this ([documentation here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#encoding-defaults)):

```
val encodeDefaultsJson = Json { encodeDefaults = true }
println(encodeDefaultsJson.encodeToJsonElement(test))
```